# Shared Data Extension Not Visible

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

Create a folder and about 10 data extension's all are under the "Shared Data Extensions" using SOAP. When we access Marketing Cloud, only folder is visible and DE are not visible.

Via SOAP, if we retrieve the DE, we can see the created DE's are there.

Is there any permission object needs to be passed when creating the shared DE to make it visible? If so, can someone share knowledge on this.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the response, found out the issue.

VIA SOAP API we need to use the Parent BU to create the folder and data extensions inside it, after that the DE's are visible across all BU's without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

### **TLDR:** Check the folder sharing permissions and add the DE again

We ran into this an scenario that seems to be tied to the same issue. I suspect that the sharing permissions have to be modified on the folder. The folder should be set to share the its content with the relevant business units.

This has be set before the content is added to the folder.

Here is a scenerio:

- I want to share data extensions with from BU A to B, C
- When I create the Folder, I forget to add Add C to the sharing permissions
- I share add a DE to this Data extension
- I realise the error in my ways and modify the permission on the sharing folder to include C
- C will still not be able to see the data extension shared.
- C will only see additional data extension added AFTER the permissions have been granted.

Comment: Is that something can be done via SOAP API?